# Can one freely take the discrete logarithm of an element in a subset of a finite field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

Consider $\mathbb{F}_p^\times$ and $S = \{a \in \mathbb{F}_p^\times : a^n \equiv 1 \mod p\}$ for any $n$.

Suppose I have $a \in S$. If I also have that $a^j \equiv a^k \mod p$, can I just take the discrete log of both sides and conclude that $j \equiv k \mod p - 1$?

Comment: You may only conclude $j\equiv k$ modulo $a$'s multiplicative order.

Comment: Your "for any $n$" is very confusing. If you mean "for some $n$", then it obviously depends on what $n$; for $n=0$ or for $n=p-1$ you get all of $\Bbb F_p^\times$, for $n=1$ you just get $1$. If you mean "for all $n$", then it should be inside the set notation, and just gives you $\{1\}$ (like for $n=1$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be true if $a$ were a primitive root. However, consider the counterexample: $10^2 \equiv 10^4 \bmod 11$, but $2 \not\equiv 4 \bmod 10$. In fact, you always have $(-1)^2 \equiv (-1)^4 \bmod p$ but $4 \not\equiv 2 \bmod p-1$ (unless $p = 3$). We could even take the more trivial case: $1^1 \equiv 1^2 \bmod p$, but $2 \not\equiv 1 \bmod p-1$ (unless you allow 1 as a modulus).

Also, your set $S$ is a bit strange: it consists of only $\{1\}$! To say that $a^n \equiv 1 \bmod p$ for *any* $n$ means that it works for $n = 1$... I think you meant to say for *some* $n$.